# Implicit class holding mutable variable in multithreaded environment

Tags: multithreading, scala, implicit, mutability

I need to implement a `parallel` method, which takes two computation blocks, `a` and `b`, and starts each of them in a new thread. The method must return a tuple with the result values of both the computations. It should have the following signature:

```scala
def parallel[A, B](a: => A, b: => B): (A, B)
```

I managed to solve the exercise by using straight Java-like approach. Then I decided to make up a solution with implicit class. Here's it:

```
object ParallelApp extends App {

  implicit class ParallelOps[A](a: => A) {
    var result: A = _

    def spawn(): Unit = {

      val thread = new Thread {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          result = a
        }
      }
      thread.start()
      thread.join()
    }
  }

  def parallel[A, B](a: => A, b: => B): (A, B) = {
    a.spawn()
    b.spawn()
    (a.result, b.result)

  }

  println(parallel(1 + 2, "a" + "b"))

}
```

For unknown reason, I receive output `(null,null)`. Could you please point me out where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spoiler alert:** It's not complicated. It's funny, like a magic trick (if you consider reading the documentation about Java Memory Model "funny", that is). If you haven't figured it out yet, I would highly recommend to try to figure it out, otherwise it won't be funny. Someone should make a *"division-by-zero proves 2 = 4"*-riddle out of it.

---

Consider the following shorter example:

```
implicit class Foo[A](a: A) {
  var result: String = "not initialized"
  def computeResult(): Unit = result = "Yay, result!"
}

val a = "a string"
a.computeResult()

println(a.result)
```

When run, it prints

```
not initialized
```

despite the fact that we invoked `computeResult()` and set `result` to `"Yay, result!"`. The problem is that the two invocations `a.computeResult()` and `a.result` belong to two completely independent instances of `Foo`. The implicit conversion is performed twice, and the second implicitly created object doesn't know anything about the changes in the first implicitly created object. It has nothing to do with threads or JMM at all.

By the way: your code is not parallel. Calling `join` right after calling `start` doesn't bring you anything, your main thread will simply go idle and wait until another thread finishes. At no point will there be two threads that do any useful work concurrently.

Comment: Thank you for such comprehensive answer. Indeed, each time implicit conversion is performed, new object is created which holds original uninitialized value. And yes, calling `join()` after `start()` blocks the current thread until it finishes. I must've noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed a bug pointed out by Andrey Tyukin

One way to solve your problem is to use Scala Futures

[Documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).  [Tutorial](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/concurrency-with-scala-futures-tutorials-examples).
[Useful Klang Blog](https://viktorklang.com/blog/).

You'll typically need some combination of these libraries:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

an asynchronous example:

```
def parallelAsync[A,B](a: => A, b: => B): Future[(A,B)] = {
  // as per Andrey Tyukin's comments, this line runs
  // the two futures sequentially and we do not get
  // any benefit from it.  I will leave this line here
  // so others will not fall in my trap
  //for {i <- Future(a); j <- Future(b) } yield (i,j)
  Future(a) zip Future(b)
}

parallelAsync(1 + 2, "a" + "b").onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(x)
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
}
```

If you must block until both are complete, you can use this:

```
def parallelSync[A,B](a: => A, b: => B): (A,B) = {
  // see comment above
  //val f = for { i <- Future(a); j <- Future(b) } yield (i,j)
  val tuple = Future(a) zip Future(b)
  Await.result(tuple, 5 second)
}

println(parallelSync(3 + 4, "c" + "d"))
```

When running these little examples, don't forget to sleep a little bit at the end so the program won't end before the results come back

```
Thread.sleep(3000)
```

Comment: Definitely, this solution is technically correct and I would implement it that way if I had done it for production purposes. But this exercise has been taken from book "Learning Concurrent Programming in Scala" by Aleksandar Prokopec and the idea is to use concurrency primitives to solve it. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Ivan The `for { i <- ...; j <- Future(b) } yield (...)` prevents the `Future(b)` from being started before `Future(a)` completes, so, again, it's not correct, it's the same mistake as in your original code - the two computations do not run simultaneously, they run strictly one after another.

Comment: You caught me again. I'm inattentive. Yes, two futures won't run simultaneously in `for` comprehension.

Comment: Ack, thanks for the catch Andrey.  I'll edit my answer shortly to include the correct behavior and mark the existing incorrect behavior with your comments

Comment: @Ivan you could use a `for`-comprehension for that, but you would have to construct (and thereby start) both futures right away, and then collect both results in a `for`. The `Future` class is a bit quirky in this sense, because constructing a `Future` has the side-effect of starting the evaluation, therefore it actually does matter where the `Future(b)` expression is in the code (and referential transparency goes out of the window, kinda...). Anyway, it would be easier to just use `zip` here.

Comment: Indeed, `Future` is not referentially transparent.